# How to make all symbols the same in plotly scatterplot

Tags: plotly, scatter-plot, symbols

I have the following code. However, as I have about 15 providers and 12 specialties, having a different symbol for each provider makes the chart too busy. Instead, I just want the Provider symbol to be a circle for all the providers. I still want them in the key so that I can use the interactive function of the chart to select a view by provider or specialty (or both) - so I have maximum flexibility in what I can toggle on or off on the chart.

```
p2 <- df3_heat %>% 
    plot_ly() %>%
    #Plot symbols for cyl
    add_trace(type = "scatter",
              x = ~backlog, 
              y = ~performance,
              symbol = ~as.factor(Provider),
              mode = 'markers',
              marker = list(color = "grey", size = 15)) %>%
    #Overlay color for gears
    add_trace(type = "scatter",
              x = ~backlog, 
              y = ~performance,
              color = ~as.factor(Specialty),
              mode = 'markers')
              
p2
```

How can I make the chart all circles?

I've tried adding the following as the first symbol seems to be a circle but it doesn't make any difference to the chart - there's still 7 different symbol types on the chart.

```
p2 <- df3_heat %>% 
    plot_ly() %>%
    #Plot symbols for cyl
    add_trace(type = "scatter",
              x = ~backlog, 
              y = ~performance,
              symbol = ~as.factor(Provider), symbols = 1,
              mode = 'markers',
              marker = list(color = "grey", size = 15)) %>%
    #Overlay color for gears
    add_trace(type = "scatter",
              x = ~backlog, 
              y = ~performance,
              color = ~as.factor(Specialty),
              mode = 'markers')
              
p2
```